# ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)

Tags: java, api

I know that in order to create an object of ArrayList type I need to:

```
ArrayList<MyType> l = new ArrayList<MyType>();
```

I know it because I've seen this in books.

But looking at Java SE API for the ArrayList constructor I see:
`ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`

I don't understand, how would I ever get an idea to specify the type of objects my new ArrayList object would hold? How would I know from this definition that I have to specify `<MyType>` during instantiation and variable declaration?

Comment: Where are you looking because I see: "public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)"

Comment: @jzd, that's what the OP put already on this question....

Comment: btw use List<MyType> l = new ArrayList<MyType>(); it's not wrong when you use the implementation class but it's better to hide implementation details

Comment: @Gentleman: It wasn't visible until Skeet edited the post to add formatting.

Comment: @AndroidNoob  Skeet fixed your question.  However, I saw your link to the API, why are you using Java 5 instead of 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to find out if you need type parameters in your declaration, you don't look at the constructor, you look at the [class definition itself](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). The arguments of the constructors have nothing to do with the type of the object itself - a constructor can take any kind of arguments, just like any other method. Here's the class definition:

```
public class ArrayList<E>
extends AbstractList<E>
implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, Serializable
```

The `class ArrayList<E>` part says that there is a class called ArrayList and it requires one type parameter (which is called E here).

Answer (score 4):

That method is meant to copy an existing collection instance to the new ArrayList not to create on from scratch. The elements of the collection it will accept have an upper bound of type E which will be the type of your new ArrayList then.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a set of shape classes.  The base class is `Shape`, and the two implementations are `Square` and `Circle`.  Now, after you've done some specific setup for the list of objects you wanted, you need to add it all together to send it to a rendering function.  The code below should make what I'm describing a little more clear:

```
ArrayList<Square> squares = readSquares();
ArrayList<Circle> circles = readCircles();

ArrayList<Shape> queue= new ArrayList<Shape>(squares);
queue.addAll(circles);

renderShapes(queue);
```

The `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` constructor makes line five possible.  With generics, the processor is not smart enough to automatically determine that Square extends Shape by default.  You have to tell the compiler that is what you intended.  The way you do that is with the wildcard `<? extends E>`.  Now the compiler will make sure that every object added is at least a Shape.

Answer (score 1):

That's always true when you construct an object for a class that takes a generic type.  If you scroll up to the top, you'll see Class ArrayList< E >.  That's the hint.